# Finding duplicate tuples in python

Tags: python, file

I'm still new to python, and I need some help in the syntax. What I have is a file with a lot of columns. I need to find duplicates based on different conditions. 
If I have

```
ColumnA   ColumnB   ColumnC  
Green      Land        32         
Land       Green       32   
Hello      World       01
World      Hello       01
```

Expected Output:

```
ColumnA   ColumnB   ColumnC  
Green      Land        32           
Hello      World       01
```

These two rows(which their data is reversed (A,B) and (B,A)) are considered duplicates depending on conditions in the data of the two rows. For instance, if their data in columnC is the same, they are considered duplicates and I should leave only one instance. Could you please help me in implementing this ? The columns are delimited by tabs.

Comment: add some more data and also add expected output

Comment: Sort columnA and columnB to get them in a consistent order, then do the comparison.

Comment: Have a look at the ‘pandas.Series.isduplicate()’ function.  This can be used on a column of a DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use builtin [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to handle your data file using the `DictReader` and `DictWriter` objects. Use:

```
freq = {} # keep track of visited columns
with open("input.csv") as f1, open('output.csv', 'w') as f2:
    headers = next(f1).strip().split('\t') # extract the header row
    reader = csv.DictReader(f1, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=headers)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f2, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader() # write the header row

    for line in reader:        
        cola, colb, colc = line['ColumnA'], line['ColumnB'], line['ColumnC']
        if (cola, colb, colc) in freq or (colb, cola, colc) in freq:
            # avoid duplicates
            continue

        freq[(cola, colb, colc)] = True
        writer.writerow(line) # write row from input to output file
```

After executing the above code the contents of `output.csv` will be:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
Green   Land    32
Hello   World   01
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is extremely useful, I have a small question, if there are columns between the columns A B and C, would this still work ?

Comment: Nope! Are you considering duplicates on the basis of `ColumnC` only?

Comment: My file has around 20 columns, I'm considering duplicates based on column A and B (AB-BA) only if other columns are equal. Just like the example I gave.

Comment: @yaranefaa I've updated the answer so that it will give you the desired result.

Comment: Okay, Thank you ! I will upvote your answer, with the dictreader can I read lines two by two? In other words, can I read the first two lines as one line? The third and fourth line as the second... etc.

Comment: @yaranefaa No, it just reads a single row from the input file as a dictionary. For example this dictionary will look like `{'ColumnA': 'Green', 'ColumnB': 'Land', 'ColumnC': '32'}` for the first row.